# How to collect VS Code logs in Azure Pipelines?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm authoring a VS Code extension and the integration tests only fail in the Azure Pipelines run. I need to start collecting logs from VS Code to analyze them. Locally, they appear under `%appdata%\Code\logs` (on Windows) and under `~/.config/Code/logs` on linux. But under Azure Pipelines they don't appear to be created at these locations.

Ultimately, I need to write an Azure Pipelines step that will publish these logs. Something like this:

```yaml
  - publish: ${{ parameters.logsLocation }}
    artifact: VS Code logs ($(Agent.JobName))
    displayName: Publishing VS Code logs
    condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

Does anyone know which path I should publish from?

Values for `logsLocation` that I've tried:

- $(AppData)/Roaming/Code/logs
- /home/vsts/.config/Code/logs
- ~/AppData/Roaming/Code/logs
- ~/.config/Code/logs

Answer (score 0):

This is how I eventually did it:

First, define a predictable place where the logs should be dropped via a variable in the pipeline:

```yaml
variables:
  VSCODE_DATA_DIR: $(Agent.TempDirectory)/vscode_data
```

The pipeline should then publish the logs from that location:

```yaml
- publish: $(VSCODE_DATA_DIR)/logs
  artifact: VS Code logs ($(Agent.JobName))
  displayName: Publishing VS Code logs
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

I use `$(Agent.JobName)` in the artifact name because I run my VS Code extension tests on all 3 OSs, so I may need to look at logs from each.

Finally, I update my integration test runner to pass an additional argument to the VS Code process:

```
const launchArgs: string[] = []

if (process.env.VSCODE_DATA_DIR) {
  launchArgs.push('--user-data-dir', process.env.VSCODE_DATA_DIR)
}

await runTests({ vscodeExecutablePath, extensionDevelopmentPath, extensionTestsPath, launchArgs })
```

So now any logs VS Code produces will be captured.
These logs already include *some* information about my extension. My extension can contribute more by [writing to an output channel](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#OutputChannel), which is automatically captured in a log file.
The other thing I can do is direct log files into the `context.logUri` directory (as [suggested here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#ExtensionContext)), but that's more work, and the APIs for writing files by URI that VS Code offers are weak (you can't append a line to a log file, for example).